# Click function of li tag not working with href other than #

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my navigation menu:

```
<ul id="nav">
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Recipies</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

I have a green leaf showing up when li is clicked, jQuery code to make it happen:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $( "#nav li" ).click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass('greenLeaf').siblings('li').removeClass('greenLeaf');

});
});
```

Now, the problem is, when instead of the "index.html", I have the # - works like charm, if a link is inserted, I need to use the event.preventDefault, which also prevents the browser to follow the link - which is obviously not exactly what I'm after. Any method to get around this problem? I'm sure it's an easy fix, but I can't figure it out...

Comment: Um, if the browser follows the link then your `addClass` is useless...the next page is loading?

Comment: What do you mean by if a link is inserted?  Are the links dynamically added client-side in some way?

Comment: So what do you want to happen when somebody clicks on a link? Do you want a leaf to appear, or do you want the default link behavior?

Comment: as i understand he want to load a new page and mark the related link with a greenLeaf after it is loaded

Comment: @DimaK So a change of what the `:visited` attribute does?

Comment: It worked fine as long as the href attribute of the anchor tag was '#'. Then I tried to use a valid anchor tag, and that's when I ran into problems. I'm newbie when it comes to jQuery, so be patient...

Comment: @NoemiTotos It works fine with the #, because that does not redirect the user anywhere. It just stays on the same page, and therefore the green leaf can be displayed. I don't really understand how you want both the link to work AND the leaf to be displayed?

Comment: @Dima K - that's exactly what I'm after. To load a new page and mark the link with the greenLeaf after it's loaded.

Comment: @NoemiTotos So there should be a green leaf when you return to the page at a later stage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you want a CSS rule:

```
#nav li a:visited{
  /* Add greenLeaf class code here */
}
```

As discussed in the comments, you want to use the css that you are using for .greenLeaf inside the :visited selector.

Comment: Thanks, is there any other way using jQuery instead of CSS?

Comment: Since you will be navigating away from the page you would need it to be a static rule that will be preserved across page loads.  jQuery is a javascript run on the client-side.  If you wanted, you could use localStorage to store a value that link X was clicked, then every page load you would check the localStorage and set the class via jQuery.  However in older browsers that do not support localStorage you would need a cookie.  I would say the CSS option is best.  Plus it can be cached and would be the fastest method.

Answer (score 0):

as i understand you are trying to mark the current page in the menu

so its something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#nav a" ).each(function(){
     if ($(this).attr("href") == window.location.pathname){
      $(this).addClass("greenLeaf");
     }
    });
});
```

Comment: This would only apply a leaf next to the current link the page was on.  This wouldn't track which have been clicked/visited.

Comment: as i understand this is what he is trying to do - mark the current page in the menu